# Control MIDI message with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, message, midi, cc

The idea of this  originally to convert NRPN+/- message to CC (with MIDIPipe)

1. MidiPipe converts the NRPN messages to CC97 1 and CC96 1
2. Set the new Channel + CC + Value

   > on runme(message)
   >
   > if (item 2 of message = 96) then
   >
   > set message to {178, 22, 1}
   >
   > else
   >
   > set message to {178, 22, 127}
   >
   > end if
   >
   > return message
   >
   > end runme
3. Makes this output twice as many messages because it is not sensitive enough?
4. Stop the leak of the original messages? This only seems to add messages not replace

I hope you can help me out how to achieve those last 2 points with AppleScript